# Infinite Scroll for both Index, Category and Archive

Tags: plugins, pagination

I want to use Infinite Scroll in my WP theme for both Index, Category and Archive. The official WP plug-in doesn't seem to support IS for Category and Archive so I figured I'd make a manual install, however I can't get it to function properly.

For example, this is what my category.php looks like -

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

    <?php get_sidebar(); ?>

    <div id="category">
        <?php $category = get_the_category(); query_posts('cat=' . $category[0]->cat_ID . '&paged=' . $paged); ?>
        <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
            <article>
                <?php the_content(); ?>
            </article>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    </div>

    <div id="pagination">
        <?php next_posts_link(); ?>
    </div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

I include the latest release of IS found at https://github.com/paulirish/infinite-scroll/, then run it with it's default settings where I set #category to be the container in effect, and article the itemSelector. navSelector is set to #pagination and nextSelector to #pagination a:first, which seems right. Nothing happens, though I get no JS errors. I see the static next post link and it works as it should. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

It's a little bit of code, so I'll ask you to take a look at [this theme](http://vinicius.soylocoporti.org.br/monospace2-wordpress-theme/) I did. It [implements infinite scroll](https://github.com/viniciusmassuchetto/wordpress-monospace2/blob/10a797b5443e57526b88fb244ff43b6cebacdfab/functions.php#L42) for the home page, category and tags, and i'll soon implement this functionality for other types of listings like archives and search.

Comment: Thanks, not sure I might be able to solve it but I'll have a look.